# Image and text block

Tags: math-mode, multicol, circuitikz, block

I do school project, there are a circuitikz circuits and some equations to each one. I'd like to keep it together and put the picture to the left, and equations on the right - as on the attached picture. Also don't want the block to cover the previous one. Tried multicols, but it forces both columns to be the same width and also doesn't allow me to add any space above the equations. Any idea? Thanks. It looks like

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\centering
\resizebox{8cm}{!}{
    \begin{circuitikz} \draw
      (0,0) to[dcvsource, l=$U_{12}$] (0,4)
      %connect 0,0 with R1
      (0, 4) -- (0.75, 4)
      to[R, *-*, l=$R_{12}$] (4,4)
      %parallel R1,2, R3
      (0.75,4) -- (0.75,2)
      to[R, -*, l=$R_3$] (4,2)

      to[R, l=$R_4$] (4, 4)

      to[R, l=$R_5$] (8, 4)

      (8,4) -- (8,0)
      (4,2) -- (4, 2)
      to[R, -*, l=$R_6$] (8,2)
      (8, 0) -- (4, 0)
      to[R, l=$R_{78}$]
      (2, 0) -- (0,0)
    ;
    \end{circuitikz}
}
\columnbreak
\begin{itemize}
    \item $R_{12} = R_1 + R_2$
    \item $U = U_1 + U_2$
\end{itemize}
\end{multicols}
```

[image: sth like this]

Comment: Maybe two `minipages`. But the complexity of equations could change the approach. Try to show us some code so we can compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
Using \verb|\parbox[text]{width}{text}|:

\parbox[c]{.5\linewidth}{%
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=.6] \draw
      (0,0) to[dcvsource, l=$U_{12}$] (0,4)
      %connect 0,0 with R1
      (0, 4) -- (0.75, 4)
      to[R, *-*, l=$R_{12}$] (4,4)
      %parallel R1,2, R3
      (0.75,4) -- (0.75,2)
      to[R, -*, l=$R_3$] (4,2)

      to[R, l=$R_4$] (4, 4)

      to[R, l=$R_5$] (8, 4)

      (8,4) -- (8,0)
      (4,2) -- (4, 2)
      to[R, -*, l=$R_6$] (8,2)
      (8, 0) -- (4, 0)
      to[R, l=$R_{78}$]
      (2, 0) -- (0,0)
    ;
    \end{circuitikz}
}%
\parbox[c]{.5\linewidth}{%
\begin{itemize}
    \item $R_{12} = R_1 + R_2$
    \item $U = U_1 + U_2$
\end{itemize}
}

Or using \verb|\begin{figure*}[placement] \end{figure*}|:
\begin{figure*}[h]\centering
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=.6] \draw
      (0,0) to[dcvsource, l=$U_{12}$] (0,4)
      %connect 0,0 with R1
      (0, 4) -- (0.75, 4)
      to[R, *-*, l=$R_{12}$] (4,4)
      %parallel R1,2, R3
      (0.75,4) -- (0.75,2)
      to[R, -*, l=$R_3$] (4,2)

      to[R, l=$R_4$] (4, 4)

      to[R, l=$R_5$] (8, 4)

      (8,4) -- (8,0)
      (4,2) -- (4, 2)
      to[R, -*, l=$R_6$] (8,2)
      (8, 0) -- (4, 0)
      to[R, l=$R_{78}$]
      (2, 0) -- (0,0)
    ;
    \node[right] at (9,3) {\textbullet\ $ R_{12} = R_1 + R_2$};
    \node[right] at (9,1) {\textbullet\ $U = U_1 + U_2$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that to maintain the coherence left-right, you have to do a lot of visual design, which is not the strong point of LaTeX. What I use is normally a `wrapfigure`, but it has its caveats (sometime behaves in a strange way and you have to force it, you'll find a lot of Q&A here about it). For  example (straight from my course material):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}\deactivatequoting
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\shunt}{\mathop{/\!/}}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

bla blah blah blah blah, 
para obtner:

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{circuitikz}[american]
            \draw (0,0) to[sV=$v_{th}$, ] ++(0,-3) node[ground](GND){}; %notice the worng +-, uffff
            \draw (0,0) to [R=${R_{th}}$] ++(2,0)
                to [C=${C}$, ] ++(1.5,0) coordinate (n2)
                to  [R=${R_L}$] (n2 |- GND) node[ground]{};
            \draw (n2) to [short, -o] ++(1,0) node [right] {$v_{o2}$};
        \end{circuitikz}
\end{wrapfigure}
y donde los equivalentes de Thévènin son:
\begin{align}
    R_{th} &= R_p\shunt r_d = \SI{667}{\ohm} \\
    v_{th} &= \frac{r_d}{R_p + r_d} v_s = \frac{2}{3}v_s
\end{align}
\dots y de paso, nota que:
\begin{equation}
    \frac{v_{o2}}{v_s}\bigg\vert_{f\to\infty} = \frac{R_L}{R_L+R_{th}} v_{th} =
    \num{0.4}v_s
\end{equation}
que lógicamente coincide con el resultado anterior.

\end{document}
```

[image]